# JAVA check statement to get value on first execution of statement

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
HashMap intermediateIdMap = new HashMap(d_idMap.size());
    int     linkCounter       = 0;

    for (Iterator it = d_idMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        Map.Entry me    = ((Map.Entry) it.next());
        long      oldId = (Long) me.getKey();
        MapObject mo    = d_mc.findMapObject(oldId);

        if (mo != null && !isMetaDataType(mo)
                && (IdSpace.isTransient(mo.id()) || d_updateAllIds
                        || isNegativeIdUpdate(mo.id())))
        {
            int transientId = d_idGenerator.getNewId();
```

I need to get the first transientId when its executed for the very first time and the Id it sets and also the last Id i.e MIN_TRANSIENT and MAX_TRANSIENT

I tried changing the Data Structure to LinkedHashMap which would have given me the 1st and Last element easily but i guess seniors dont want me to change the ds, do you guys help me find an another way

```
public synchronized int getNewId()
{
    // Contract.precondition("Within range", d_currentId <= d_range);
    // CMSDL-3988 - recycle/reset the currentId once max reached
    if(d_currentId>d_range)
        d_currentId=MIN_TRANSIENT;

    return d_currentId++;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you write `HashMap` instead of `HashMap<Long, WhateverYoPutInThere>`? And why you don't use `for (Map.Entry<…> me : d_idMap.entrySet())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need changes for a reason, you should be allowed to do them.

Otherwise, you need some structure around your code such as

```
boolean firstValueSeen = false;
int firstValue = -1;

for (…) {
        …
            int transientId = d_idGenerator.getNewId();
            firstValueSeen = true;
            firstValue = transientId
```